# Error generating pdf using prawn

Tags: ruby, pdf, prawn

I am trying to use tags to give some styling for a pdf being generated using prawn. But, there seems to be an error.

```
require 'rubygems' 
require 'prawn'
require 'prawn/layout'
require 'prawn/format'

Prawn::Document.generate "example.pdf" do 
        tags:h1=>{ :font_size => "16pt", :font_weight => :bold }
        text"<h1>Student Details</h1>" 
end
```

I get the following error -

```
 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/prawn-format-0.2.3/lib/prawn/format/text_object.rb:91:in `%': can't convert nil into Float (TypeError)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be:

```
tags[:h1] = { :font_size => "16pt", :font_weight => :bold }
```

?

Also please note that:

> As of Prawn 0.7, prawn-format is completely unsupported, and will not
>   work with versions of Prawn 0.7+. Feel free to fork and fix, of
>   course.

Consider using methods from Prawn::Text

http://rubydoc.info/gems/prawn/0.12.0/Prawn/Text

**EDIT**

For example:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'prawn'

Prawn::Document.generate('font_calculations.pdf') do
  font "Courier", :size => 16, :style => :bold
  text "Student details"
  font "Courier", :size => 12, :style => :normal
  text "normal text"
  text "this is normal, <b>but this is bold</b>", :inline_format => true
  text "normal <font size='18'>bigger</font> normal", :inline_format => true
end
```

That's just one of many ways of doing this.

Comment: @verdure Prawn 0.2.3 is kind of old (aka 2008). Any reason you need this version?

Comment: I have checked my version of Prawn and updated it to 0.12.0, but the error still persists.

Comment: @verdure As I said prawn-format is unsupported, and `tags` are part of it. See update.